# Using Promises with Nodejs v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my earlier applications I've done something along the lines (using Express)

```
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
```

In the top of my `routes` and then within my functions, I can string functions together with `.then` and `.catch` and so forth.

I read that Node v4 merged the codebase of iojs which added in promises. So my question, do I still need to require the npm module bluebird to use promises in my Nodejs & Express application or can I just use promises right of the back?

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question, thanks!

Comment: if **all** you're doing with promises is covered by https://promisesaplus.com/ then you should be right without adding bluebird. If you're using bluebird cruft then continue to require bluebird

Comment: Native Promises are pretty basic implementations at the moment. But bluebird provides a lot of helper functions. So, if you don't want all those functions and sacrifice a little on the performance (I heard that the native promises are slightly slower than bluebird), you can use native promises.

Comment: Ahh awesome, I wasn't even aware there were any performance effects from using native vs bluebird, thanks! @thefourtheye